# C memory management with more pointers to the same location

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory-management

I was playing with this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int *p){
    free(p);
}

int main(){
    int *i = calloc(3, sizeof(int));
    function(i);
    i[0] = 'a';
    printf("%c\n", i[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected to get an error, but instead it printed 'a', if 'a' is deallocated why does it print it? What happens in function(int *p) has any effect if the main()?(if you can, explain what happen to that 'p' pointer)

Suppose that I have those two in the same function:

```
int *a = malloc(...);
int *b = a;
```

Both of them point to the same piece of memory, but when I have to free it, should I call free on both of them, or just one of them?(again explain why if possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have returned the memory to the heap, but the memory isn't reused yet. So, sometimes the memory contents remain the same and you can read and write it as if it where still in use.

But you should never use memory that is already freed, since there's no guarantee how long the memory stays this way.

In your second part `a = malloc(...); b = a`, both variables point to the very same memory. Since this is just *one* piece of bytes, you must `free()` it exactly *once*. Otherwise you have a double free, which might corrupt the heap.

*Update* for @SSHThis's question:

`free(a)` only returns the memory to the heap. It doesn't modify `a` or `b`. The check `if(a)` or `if(b)` evaluates to true, whether the memory was freed or not. Only when you set `a` or `b` to null, will the check evaluate to false, whether the memory was freed or not.

So `free(a)` and `if(a)` are independent operations. They don't influence each other.

```
a = malloc(10); /* assuming malloc doesn't return NULL */
if (a) {
    /* will be true, memory is NOT freed */
}

free(a);
if (a) {
    /* will be true, although memory is freed */
}

a = malloc(10); /* assuming malloc doesn't return NULL */
a = NULL;
if (a) {
    /* will NOT be true, although memory is NOT freed */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer, it makes more sense to me. I have one lingering question, that may not merit a whole new question. Using variable names from you example, if `b` could be equal to `a` or `b` could also possibly be equal to some newly malloc'ed memory, could I `free(a)` and then do a check like `if(b) free(b)`? I'm assuming that if the former were true, `a` would be freed, and consequently `if(b)` would not evaluate as true?

Answer (score 5):

That is undefined behavior. Freeing the pointer just tells the OS that the memory allocated can be overwritten. The memory is still there.. for lack of a better word. But anything can happen.. it may print a for you now, at other times it could be another character or number because another program has written to that memory location... anything can happen.

For your last question.. a and b are just symbolic names to an address. Calling free on the address is important, so whether you do `free(a)` or `free(b)`, you are grand.

Answer (score 3):

It prints 'a' because you are lucky. This is undefined behavior. Its currently 'de-allocated' and which means, it(the memory location) is flagged for 'overwriting'

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong, but getting an error implies something is checking that it is wrong.  There are many things in C that you can do that are wrong but are never checked.  This is typically done because there would be a performance penalty for doing the checking, or it is just a very difficult thing to check for.  Accessing memory that has been freed is one of those things.  Running your program through a tool like valgrind will report more of these kinds of problems, but the program will run much slower.

Here is the output from valgrind:

```
==19080== Invalid write of size 4
==19080==    at 0x8048468: main (main.c:11)
==19080==  Address 0x403b028 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 12 free'd
==19080==    at 0x4006EED: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:366)
==19080==    by 0x8048434: function (main.c:5)
==19080==    by 0x8048463: main (main.c:10)
==19080== 
==19080== Invalid read of size 4
==19080==    at 0x8048472: main (main.c:12)
==19080==  Address 0x403b028 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 12 free'd
==19080==    at 0x4006EED: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:366)
==19080==    by 0x8048434: function (main.c:5)
==19080==    by 0x8048463: main (main.c:10)
==19080==
```